# StackOverflow error due to recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, maze

I'm attempting to use recursive methods to solve a maze represented by an int array of 1s and 0s in Java. wasHere[] checks if the method has already parsed that particular set of coordinates, correctPath[] records the answer path to the maze; both of them are initialized with every index being false.

```
import java.awt.Point;
class mazeSolver{
   int[][] maze;
   int startX, startY; 
   int endX, endY;     
   int width, height;
   boolean[][] wasHere, correctPath;

   mazeSolver(int[][] m, int sX,int sY,int nX,int nY){
      maze = m;
      width = maze[0].length;
      height = maze.length;
      startX = sX;
      startY = sY;
      endX = nX;
      endY = nY;
      System.out.println("Height: " + height + "\t Width: " + width);

      correctPath = new boolean[height][width];
      wasHere = new boolean[height][width];
      for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++)  
         for (int col = 0; col < maze[row].length; col++){
            wasHere[row][col] = false;
            correctPath[row][col] = false;
         }
      solveMaze(startX,startY);
   }

     public boolean solveMaze(int x, int y){
      boolean solvable = recursiveSolve(x,y);
      return solvable;
     }

     private boolean recursiveSolve(int x, int y){ //1s are walls, 0s are free space
      if (x == endX && y == endY)
         return true;
      if (wasHere[y][x] || maze[y][x] == 1)
         return false;

      wasHere[y][x] = true;

      if (y < height-1){
         if (solveMaze(x,y+1))
            return true;
      }

      if (y > 0){
         if (solveMaze(x,y-1))
            return true;
      }

      if (x > 0){
         if (solveMaze(x-1,y))
            return true;
      }

      if (x < width-1){
         if (solveMaze(x+1,y)) 
            return true;
      }

      return false;
   }

   public int[][] getSolvedMaze(){
      for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
         for (int x = 0; x< width; x++)
            if(correctPath[y][x])
               maze[y][x] = 2;
      return maze;
   }
}
```

I have been stuck with this error for the past few hours, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Paste your complete code.

Comment: It's possible there is no bug. How big is your maze? The stack is finite, so for every stack there's a big enough maze to overflow it.

Comment: @BarryFruitman My test maze is 300x400. I'd preferably like to process ones that are 2000x2000 though also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no bug as such (not that I can see) but you are recursing way too much which caused this issue. I am not sure what values are you feeding into the program, but I was able to notice the issue with initializing the above program with these parameters:

```
mazeSolver MazeSolver = new  mazeSolver(new int [100][100], 0, 0, 100,100);
```

So to run your program as-it-is I increased the stack size. You could do so by feeding the following parameter to JVM as you run the program: `-Xss258m`

This stack size was able to accommodate array of 1000 size. I did not have much time to test other sizes.

```
mazeSolver MazeSolver = new  mazeSolver(new int [1000][1000], 0, 0, 1000,1000);
```

Comment: I set the run arguments to -Xss258m as you suggested, then to -Xss2580m and neither of them worked :/. My array is roughly 300x400, which is odd since 258 megabytes worked for your 1000x1000 array. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Can you show how you are doing it? If it worked for me, it has to for you. Also print  "java -version" and paste it here please.

Comment: Here is the way I ran: ../jdk1.6.0_38/bin/java -Xss218m mazeSolver

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ruHroYN.png - That's how I set the argument (IDE is called jGrasp). Here is the output:


java version "1.8.0_40"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I am not a jGrasp expert, but quickly downloading and trying it out shows that the jGrasp is setting the arguments this way: java mazeSolver -Xss218m. This is not going to work. To test what I am recommending, try the command line approach. Go to command line, execute java with arguments EXACTLY like I showed you. If jGrasp can't set the runtime stack size for a Java program...I'd rather use Eclipse which had pretty straightforward way to set JVM arguments for programs...

Comment: Yeah, it worked when I set it there. I'm not sure why though, as I thought that column was for multiple parameters. Anyways, thank you so much and I really wish you the best